# php, difference between multiple dates

Tags: php, date, difference

I have multiple dates for example:
1395637200
1402894800
1403499600

What I want to do with them is checking which one of them is:
a. the "previous" date
b. the "next" date
How can I do this in PHP with a lot of them (±100-500)?

Comment: You need code for doing this. So where is the code...?

Comment: I don't have any code, because I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Store them into an array, sort them with sort() and all your date will be ordered from the older to newer. Is it what your want ?

Comment: No I want them to compare them to the date of today and then check which one was the last date before today and which one is the next. I already have them in an array sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Current array of dates
$dates = array(1395637200, 1402894800, 1403499600);

// Add current date to array and store in $cur
$dates[] = $cur = time();

// Sort dates (with current date added)
sort($dates);

// Get key of current date
$today = array_search($cur, $dates);

// If current date is first in array, there is no previous date.
// Otherwise, get date for previous key
$prev = $today == 0 ? NULL : $dates[$today-1];

// If current date is last in array, there is no next date.
// Otherwise get date for next key
$next = $today == count($dates)-1 ? NULL : $dates[$today+1];
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/jyUVaWcd)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of time difference in minutes.

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:21:00");
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
```

In this way, you can find difference in hours by dividing with 60 once again

then if you want to find difference in days then divide with 60*60*24

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want ? There is certainly a proper way to do that.

```
$dates = array("1395637200","1402894800","1403499600");
$previousDate = "";
$nextDate = "";
$now = time();

foreach($dates as $date)
{
    // Older
    if($date < $now) {
        $previousDate = $date;
    }
    // Next
    elseif($date > $now)
    {
        $nextDate = $date;
    }
}

echo "Previous date is $previousDate <br> Next date is $nextDate ";
```